# Chi-Square test for groups of unequal size

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics, chi-squared

I'd like to apply chi-square test `scipy.stats.chisquare`. And the total number of observations is different in my groups.

```
import pandas as pd

data={'expected':[20,13,18,21,21,29,45,37,35,32,53,38,25,21,50,62],
      'observed':[19,10,15,14,15,25,25,20,26,38,50,36,30,28,59,49]}

data=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data.expected.sum())
print(data.observed.sum())
```

*To ignore this is incorrect - right?*

Does the default behavior of `scipy.stats.chisquare` takes this into account? I checked with pen and paper and looks like it doesn't. Is there a parameter for this?

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
# incorrect since the number of observations is unequal 
chisquare(f_obs=data.observed, f_exp=data.expected)
```

When I do manual adjustment I get slightly different result.

```
# adjust actual number of observations
data['obs_prop']=data['observed'].apply(lambda x: x/data['observed'].sum())
data['observed_new']=data['obs_prop']*data['expected'].sum()

# proper way
chisquare(f_obs=data.observed_new, f_exp=data.expected)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong at some point. Thanks.

ps: I tagged R for additional statistical expertise

Comment: I don't understand your question. Both groups have 16 observations. What do you mean "And the total number of observations is different in my groups."?

Comment: The observations are the sum of each vector, not the number of categories. If the sums are different, it is probably due to rounding error in computing the expected values.

Comment: I think the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site is a better forum for this question.

Comment: Ok. will forward this question there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this was a different statistical problem - Chi-square test of independence of variables in a contingency table.

```
from scipy.stats import contingency as cont
chi2, p, dof, exp=cont.chi2_contingency(data)
p
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question quite well. However, the way I see it is that you can use *scipy.stats.chi2_contingency* if you want to compute the independence test between two categorical variable.
Also the *scipy.stats.chi2_sqaure* can be used to compare observed vs expected. Here the number of categories should be the same. Logicaly a category would get a 0 frequency if there is an observed frequecy but the expeceted frequency does not exist and vice-versa.

Hope this helps